# Conditionally Merging two lines into one line

Tags: unix, merge, bioinformatics

**How can I merge two lines if the have met specific criteria in Unix terminal?**

I have data like:

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
A4
A5
B5
```

And I want to merge to like that:

```
A1, B1
A2, B2
A3,
A4,
A5, B5
```

Real data looks like this:

```
"224222" 
<Frequency freq="0.136" allele="T" sampleSize="5008"/>
"224223" 
<Frequency freq="0.3864" allele="T" sampleSize="5008"/>
"224224" 
"224225" 
<Frequency freq="0.3894" allele="G" sampleSize="5008"/>
"1801179" 
"1861759"
```

I actually tried to add dummy deliminator texts to before the "A" data to separate them. But I couldn't achive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/$/, /;N;/\n<Freq/{s/\n//};P;D' <file>
```

Explanation:

- `s/$/, /` - Append a comma to the current line
- `N` - Get the next line
- `/\n<Freq/{s/\n//}` - If the second line contains `<Freq`, delete the newline
- `P` - Print first portion of pattern space
- `D` - Delete first portion of pattern space

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [awk getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html):
`awk '{ if(condition){ if((getline var)>0) print $0","$var; else print $0; } else print $0;}' <file>`